# Circular buffer of <Mat> holds less than it should

Tags: c++, multithreading, video-streaming, buffer, circular-buffer

I'm processing a video stream, using a boost circular buffer of `Mat` in a C++ code. One thread pushes `Mat` objects:

```
void* capture(void* arg){
    boost::circular_buffer<Mat> cb(2000);
    Mat frame;
        while ((VideoCapture >> frame), !frame.empty()) {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
                cb.push_back(frame);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        }
}
```

other thread processes and pops them:

```
void* process(void* arg){
    while (1){
        Mat frame;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        frame =cb.front();
        cb.pop_front();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        scan(frame);           
    }
}
```

However, even with a full buffer, there is no delay compared to the video stream. I checked the first (front) image in the buffer `cb[1]` and the last (back) image, when the buffer was full `cb[1999]` and they are both the same, also the same as the last captured image from the stream.
    It is as if the buffer holds only the last captured image and retrieves it for any called slot. Any ideas why the buffer isn't storing all the images that it should be?

Comment: Are you using OpenCV rigth?

Comment: [`circular_buffer::push_back`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/implementation.html#circular_buffer.implementation.writing_to_a_full_buffer) will overwrite old data when the buffer is full. If your producer thread, `capture`, pushes faster than your consumer thread, `process`, can pop, you'll lose frames. You'll need to implement some mechanism for the producer to throttle itself in the event that the buffer is full.

Comment: @SeanCline Yes, but the first and the last frame in the buffer should still be different. I used UHD video stream and slow processing to fill the buffer up on purpose. Normally the buffer is empty.

Comment: @Rama Yes. Everything works, except for the buffer. Well the buffer also _works_, as in i can put frames into it and retrieve them, it also fills up and empties as expected, but all the frames in it seem to be the same as the last captured frame.

Comment: @arvids Ahh, I see what you mean. I think you're being bitten by `cv::Mat`'s shallow-copy semantics. Can you try moving the `Mat frame;` declaration down into the `while` loop? That should make sure all the instances of `Mat` have their own buffer instead of sharing one.

Comment: @SeanCline Thank you! That worked. Going to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Sean Cline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020072/sean-cline) i was able to solve this problem.
I had to change my capture thread from:

```
void* capture(void* arg){
    boost::circular_buffer<Mat> cb(2000);
    Mat frame;
        while ((VideoCapture >> frame), !frame.empty()) {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
                cb.push_back(frame);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        }
}
```

to:

```
void* capture(void* arg){
    boost::circular_buffer<Mat> cb(2000);
    Mat frame;
        while ((VideoCapture >> frame), !frame.empty()) {
                Mat image;
                frame.copyTo(image);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
                cb.push_back(image);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        }
}
```

So that the `Mat` object that is pushed into the buffer is declared in the same `while` loop. I used `copyTo()`, because the `Mat` frame is used in the conditions of the `while` loop. This makes all the instances of `Mat image` have their own buffer instead of sharing one.

Comment: exactly what I needed! Works like a charm with only limit being RAM size.